# Creating a Responsive Flex Layout of Items Using Phone Width and Maintaining Aspect Ratio

Tags: css, flexbox

Would love some help from the CSS flex masters out there.

1. I have a n-count list of 4:3 aspect ratio items which should layout and take the full width of the page.
2. When the page resizes horizontally the grid of items should wrap.
3. On a phone, the items should all be one column with their width equal to the phone with minus a little bit of padding.

I've got this which is pretty close: https://codepen.io/kirkouimet/pen/gOLrmvL

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

li {
    margin: 32px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    
    list-style-type: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

The problem I am having is with #3. Some phones have smaller widths than others, so I can't set a fixed width pixel size. Setting a fixed width pixel size is also a problem because I then need to maintain a 4:3 aspect ratio. The items need to have a max width as well so they look good on desktop...

Anyone have ideas on how I could approach this? I think flex and flex wrapping is the way to go. I would like to avoid JavaScript if at all possible as well.

Comment: Do you mean `a little bit of margin` in #3.

Comment: Ah yeah margin or padding, just so the items aren't flush to the edge of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc()` and `media-queries` in CSS to do so.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  body {
    background-color: #ffe897;
  }
  li {
    width: calc(100vw - 64px);
    height: calc(75vw - 64px);
  }
}
```

Here the above `media-query` will only work if the device width is less or equal to `550px`. You can change it as per your need.

The `background-color` to `body` is given just to see a when is the `media-query` start working. You can remove it after you are done with the `media-query`.

Now is the actual part:

We have assigned `width` to `calc(100vw - 64px)`. We can do all types of calculation inside `calc()`. Here `100vw` means 100% of the viewport or screen width. We are saying set the width to `100%` of the `divide width` minus `64px` which is the `margin` of `32px` on left and right side.

Similarly, the height says `75%` of the device with minus the `64px` `margin`.

*Check it in action on Codepen Editor: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJbNpqx?editors=1100*

*Check it in action on Codepen Debug Mode: https://cdpn.io/manaskhandelwal1/debug/OJbNpqx/XxkVwKaqOJxM*

---

To see the width and height calculated by the browser you can use the browser developer tools.

Open the developer tools and change the tab `Styles` to `Computed`.

[image]

You can see the values change as you change the screen width.

Comment: Manas this is amazing. Thank you very much for helping me out on this. CSS has gotten so nice to work with!

Comment: @KirkOuimet this will not keep a 4:3 ratio: (100vw / 75vw = 4/3) but ((100vw - X)/(75vw - X)) !=4/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simplified code like below without media query:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  margin: 32px;
  aspect-ratio:4 / 3; /* this a new property not yet supported everywhere */
  width:100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: #CCC;
}
/* Use the below to support all the browsers
li::before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:75%;
}
*/
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Temani - this looks awesome. I wish the aspect-ratio property was available everywhere!

Comment: @KirkOuimet you can still use the code I commented until we have more support ;)